# Merge arrays and strings into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have input like this:

```
const a = 'lol',
      b = ['1','2','3'],
      c = 'c';
```

I want to merge it so the output would be this array:

```
['lol', '1', '2', '3', 'c']
```

I tried with spread operator like this

```
const arr = [...a, ...b, ...c]
console.log(arr)
```

but it consoles

> ["l", "o", "l", "1", "2", 3, "c"]

Comment: `...a` will spread *the string* into the individual characters. Just omit the spread and have `[a, ...b, c]`

Comment: `b.unshift(a); b.push(c);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only use spread if it's an array:

```
const arr = [a, ...b, c];
```

More dynamically, with `.flat`:

```js
const a = 'lol',
      b = ['1','2','3'],
      c = 'c';
const arr = [a, b, c].flat();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: But the input can be more strings and arrays

Comment: @dopeCode then...just do the same - spread the arrays, don't spread the strings. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @dopeCode Put all items of the input into the array, then flatten that array - see the snippet.

Comment: `.flat()` won't work on Edge or IE. Just a comment.

Comment: @StackSlave neither would the spread operator, however if OP is using it, then IE doesn't seem to be a concern.

Answer (score -2):

A better way to get each element in a function.

> const a = 'lol',
>         b = ['1','2','3'],
>         c = 'c';
>
> const _join = (...params) => {  return
>   Array.prototype.concat.apply([],params) }
>
> const result = _join(a,b,c)
>
> console.log(result)

Comment: This currently fails and prints Array(9) ["l", "o", "l", "1", ",", "2", ",", "3", …]